# Implicit function theorem for Fréchet spaces and analyticity

Tags: analytic-functions, implicit-function-theorem, locally-convex-spaces

Does there exist an implicit function theorem (IFT) covering the following setting:

Consider $f\colon \mathbb{C} \times V \to V$ where $V$ is a Fréchet space, satisfying certain conditions. I wish to implicitly define $x\colon U \subset \mathbb{C} \to V$, where $U$ is an open neighborhood, such that $f(z, x(z)) = 0$ for all $z \in U$, and additionally conclude that $x$ is analytic.

Comment: There are such theorems. Do you have some specific conditions in mind?

Comment: In my concrete application, $V$ is the space of complex-valued sequences with pointwise convergence topology, and $f$ is smooth in this topology. In fact each element $f_n(x)$ is a polynomial of the $x_n$ of bounded total degree. For $z=0$ I know $x(0)$, and I want to deduce the existence and analyticity of $z\mapsto x(z)$ near zero.